# Trouble creating the exactly right Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex, apache, search, findall

I have the following regular expression(updated):
`([0-9]{2}/[a-zA-Z]{3}/[0-9]{4})(.+)(GET|POST)\s(http://|https://)([a-zA-Z-.][a-zA-Z0-9+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)(\.)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)([\.:/\s]).+?"\s200`

I also have the following lines excerpted from a long server log(updated):

```
218.5.192.147 - - [14/Mar/2004:02:31:06 -0500] "GET http://searchanytime.com" 200 - "-" "-"
202.101.150.100 - - [12/Mar/2004:21:18:55 -0500] "GET http://nationalwholesalellc.com" 200 114887 "-" "-"
```

It works as planned for these lines:

```
220.173.17.142 - - [09/Mar/2004:23:32:13 -0500] "POST http://www.canada44.ca/ HTTP/1.1" 200 27095 "http://www.so123.com" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows 95)"
212.160.136.163 - - [10/Mar/2004:01:01:46 -0500] "GET http://www.6seconds.org/ HTTP/1.0" 200 51937 "http://www.helavasearch.com/cgi-bin/search.cgi?username=amundii&keywords=parenting" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.0; Windows 98)"
218.72.85.59 - - [10/Mar/2004:01:05:13 -0500] "GET http://hpcgi1.nifty.com/trino/ProxyJ/prxjdg.cgi HTTP/1.1" 200 2221 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)"
```

In almost every situation, group 7 is my top level domain (com, cn, org, etc.).  However for the lines that have .com" instead of .com HTTP/1.1" it doesn't work and returns group 7 as "searchanytime" instead of "com"

I've been using www.regexr.com

Comment: Try this: http://www.txt2re.com/. Also sanitize the URLs in your log file sample to dummies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The Regex

From what I can see of what you are trying to do, I came up with the following:

```
(\d{2}/\w{3}/\d{4})(.+)(GET|POST)\s(http://|https://)(\w+)?\.?([\w\d]+)\.(\w+).*?200
```

## The Breakdown

I'll breakdown the regex so that if it's not 100% what you're looking for hopefully it will put you on your way

### group1

```
(\d{2}/\w{3}/\d{4})
```

captures the date on the log entry, format is DD/MMM/YYYY

### group2

```
(.+)
```

capture the filler inbetween this and the next group. from your first example, this will match `:02:31:06 -0500] "` Note: that if `POST` or `GET`

### group3

```
(GET|POST)
```

pretty self-explanitory

### filler

```
\s
```

matching a single white-space character that we don't care about

### group4

```
(http://|https://)
```

also pretty straight forward

### group5

this is where your regex broke down I think.

```
(\w+)?\.?
```

This will match the www or hpcgi1 portion of the log entry. Note the ? character making this group optional. This is for cases such as

```
[14/Mar/2004:02:31:06 -0500] "GET http://searchanytime.com" 200 - "-" "-"
```

### group6

```
([\w\d]+)
```

The middle portion (i.e. canada44, nifty) or the first portion (i.e. searchanytime)

### group7

```
([\w\d]+)
```

The end portion (i.e. com, org)

### filler

```
.*?
```

Any character (as few as possible) between the 'com', 'org', etc. and the 200. If you want to reference any of this you should capture it.

### the end

```
200
```

match a 200. Note, because of the ? in the filler above, this will be the first 200 the match encounters after group7

## Disclaimer

I have not actually tested this regex on your log messages outside of an online [regex tool](http://regexpal.com/).
I am not sure of the grouping you want/need, but hopefully this helps a little.